# Parse field from response in feature file using cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm writing a integration test case using  cucumber feature file. I'm getting the response in the following manner. But, I'm not able to understand how to parse the field values which are in a array of objects.

Here is my response

```
 [{
    "firstName": "Syed"
    "location": "Dubai"
  }]
```

I want to validate the firstName.

Here is my code

```
When I POST /details
Then response code should be 200
And response body path details[0].firstName should contain "Syed" // Throws NPE at details[0]
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to parse this `details[0].firstName` out to your step definition and run this jsonpath against your response (how you do that depends on what lib you are using for REST client)

Comment: This is a rather low level description of a feature. If this is the level you would like to test at consider using plain JUnit with Rest assured.